# Issue while casting objects

Tags: jasper-reports, libraries

I have a report with a jar library in the classpath and a datasource with objects defined in that library.

In a TextField I have this:

```
((my.custom.package.MyClass)$F{my_field}.getOne()).getOther()
```

And it compiles without problems.

But if I try this one:

```
((MyClass)$F{my_field}.getOne()).getOther()
```

The *iReport* throws an error:

```
MyClass cannot be resolved to a type.
```

Is there any form to avoid using the whole qualified name of `MyClass`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer:

Click on the report root and in the properties panel go to "Imports" and add "my.custom.package.MyClass".

Now I can use MyClass without writing the package every time.

Thanks you all.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful.

Comment: My answer was the actual and final answer to the question. The "thank you" only was a polite salutation.
Thank you for your advise anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you switch to using Groovy then you could write `$F{my_field}.one.other`

Some info about this here:
http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/creating-expressions-using-groovy

I have not done this myself though.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to place a Map as my_field and add all your properties there.

```
((java.util.Map<String,Object>)$F{my_field}).get("desired_key")
```